# Managed aquifer recharge (MAR) and Remote sensing

Tags: remote-sensing, ndvi, nasa, water

What is the process to identify with quantitative data and remote sensing, how a managed aquifer recharge (MAR) has contributed to increased water availability, There is no local data and the area is about 1082.65 km2. I was thinking of doing this by analyzing the evolution of NDVI, but I am still puzzled.